# Can't access object property after it being retrieved from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to access a property inside of an object that was retrieved by mongoose

```
 const eventToDelete=await EventModel.find({"creator":_id});
         const id_chat=eventToDelete.chat;
         console.log(eventToDelete);  
         console.log(id_chat);
```

the output:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("623c71630e1ab7b02941fe51"),
    title: 'House Party',
    description: "This Saturday 10pm",
    type: 'Party',
    lat: -37.50328,
    lng: -52.28816,
    date: 2022-03-24T13:25:27.319Z,
    creator: '623c6de2aeafdc7a0f9ac42d',
    chat: '623c71630e1ab7b02941fe52',
    __v: 0
  }
]
undefined
```

I read that apparently the console.log is not showing me the real deal because It changes the structure of the response or something like that, but I don't understand how to achieve what I need( accessing that value) that's why I'm asking for help doing so....

- I tried using a toObject() function as one of the answer to similar problems recommended

but I received the following error

```
eventToDelete.toObject is not a function
```

- I do have chat in the event schema ( that was the most recommended solution I found)

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const eventSchema= mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {type:String, required:true},
        description:  {type:String, default:''},
        type:  {type:String, default:''},
        img:{type:String, default:''},
        lat:{type:Number, default:0.0},
        lng:{type:Number, default:0.0},
        date:{type:Date, default:new Date()},
        creator: {type:String, required:true},
        chat: {type:String, default:''},
     
    }
)

const EventModel= mongoose.model("EventModel",eventSchema);
export default EventModel;
```

What am I missing ?
Please help!

Comment: I'd try logging with `JSON.stringify(eventToDelete, null, 4)` this might give you a better output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to access the property because `.find()` returns an array.

You can see that the object you get from `console.log(eventToDelete)` have `[]` around it.

You will have to do something like this

```
const id_chat = eventToDelete[0].chat;
```

You can use `.findOne()` if you are expecting only one result from your query

Check [here how to use .findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)